# Erro ao fazer uma requisição POST Angular (SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse)

Tags: angular, http

Angular:

```
public urlConvenio: string = "http://localhost/teste/sistema/backend/controller/convenio/listar.php";

const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   })
};

//REQUISIÇÃO
public enviaDados() {
    this.http.post(this.urlPost, 
                   JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value), 
                   this.httpOptions).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
    })
 }
```

Erro:

[image: msg de erro]

Servidor:

[image: codigo php]

Comment: Acho que vc nao precisa do stringify, o angular ja fiz isso pra vc como padrao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o cabeçalho **responseType** na sua constante **httpOptions**

```
 const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'responseType': 'text' })
    }
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, valeu amigo!